# Dropdown Menu styling issues CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a dropdown menu with CSS, it different options depending on the page it could be 1 or 2 options, I will share the css code. My issue is why the position of the tooltip dialog changed depending on how many options do we have:

This is how it looks like with two options:
[image: This is how looks like with 2 options]

This is how it looks like with 1 option:
[image: This is how looks like with 1 option]

As you can see the position change according with the number of options, here is the code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tooltip {
  min-width: 10rem;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 2rem;
  height: auto;
  background-color: var(--app-secondary-color);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1.2rem #CCC;
  transform: translate(-25%, calc(40%));
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 0;
}

.tooltip:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: -10px;
  left: calc(75% - 10px);
  border-bottom: solid 5px var(--app-secondary-color);
  border-left: solid 10px transparent;
  border-right: solid 10px transparent;
  border-top: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <i>Icon picture</i>
  <div id="tooltipTop" class="tooltip">
    <span>Option 1</span>
    <span>Option 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What do you think should I changed on my css or do am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `calc(40%)` and instead try using `margin-top` to fix the dropdown.

```
.tooltip {
      margin-top: 2em;
      min-width: 10rem;
      width: auto;
      min-height: 2rem;
      height: auto;
      background-color: var(--app-secondary-color);
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      padding: 1rem;
      flex-direction: column;
      box-shadow: 0 0.3rem 1.2rem #CCC;
      transform: translate(-25%);
      border-radius: 3px;
      top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, really appreciate your time to respond, thanks